# Cross Field Validation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

Hoping I've provided enough info : Using the below links is anyone able to reproduce making Cross Field Validation form into one field that has a customer `Your code must be 4 digits.`  &  no error once 4 digit pin is entered (only any 4 numbers `eg.(1234),(0000),(9999)` (not any other characters))

https://codesandbox.io/s/s023f

https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/advanced/rules-object-expression.html#cross-field-validation

Below is my Attempt with `import { extend } from "vee-validate";`  example using regex `/^\d{4}$/`  on equalFourDigits but I'm still seeing the custom message when 4 numbers are entered - I want to keep the custom message.

```js
<script>
import { extend } from "vee-validate";

extend("equalFourDigits", {
  params: ["equalFourDigits"],
  validate: ({  equalFourDigits }) => {
    if ( equalFourDigits ===  /^\d{4}$/ ) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  },
  message:
    "Your code must be 4 digits. {equalFourDigits}"
});

export default {
  data: () => ({
    firstValue: '',
    secondValue: '',
    equalFourDigits: ''
  })
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <ValidationObserver>
    <ValidationProvider :rules="{ required: true, numeric: 4,  equalFourDigits: { equalFourDigits: 
     equalFourDigits }}" v-slot="{ errors }">
      <input type="text" v-model.number="secondValue">
      <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
    </ValidationProvider>
  </ValidationObserver>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can just use `:rules="{required: true, digits:4}"` instead?

```
import {digits} from 'vee-validate/dist/rules';
extend('digits', {
  ...digits,
  message: `only four digits ...!!!!`,
})
```

or

```
extend("equalFourDigits", {
  validate: (value) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(/^\d{4}$/)
    if (regex.test(value)) {
      return true;
    }
    return `Your code must be 4 digits. ${value}`;
  },
});
```

Comment: extend("equalFourDigits", {
  validate: (value) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(/^\d{4}$/)
    if (regex.test(value)) {
      return true;
    }
    return `Your code must be 4 digits. ${value}`;
  },
});  maybe change the condition a bit?

Comment: changed my condition to ```:rules="{ required: true, digits: 4,  equalFourDigits: { equalFourDigits: 
     equalFourDigits }}"``` no luck                            Original answer was correct but if i have the type set to text in the input it doesn't display originally error  ``` Please enter digits only``` i would need to change the type to number the users unable to type characters all together